# Square Gift Card Balance

Tags: square-connect

Is there a way to check the balance of Square gift cards through the API? I'm making an app on behalf of a merchant at a school who would like to facilitate mobile orders through the use of prepaid gift cards.

According to the [user documentation](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/6000-square-egift-cards), the receipt of a transaction received by the customer will display any remaining balance, but when I look at the [API documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-transaction) no such information seems to be provided.

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You were right to check out the documentation. At this time there isn't an API for any giftcard functionality, including checking balances.